# Double sided image on Animate CSS Flip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm currently flipping an image using the following code:

```
$(".image").html('<img class="winner" src="'+result[1]+'"/>');
$('.winner').addClass('animated flip');
```

However, I want to have 2 images when flipping, so currently you just see the same image spinning round, I want to be able to see 2 images on either side of the flip, is this possible?

Thanks

Comment: You need to set [`backface-visibility: hidden`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/backface-visibility). [Example](https://davidwalsh.name/css-flip)

Comment: @Blazemonger Ok I understand that, so how do I declare the backface image?

Comment: @Blazemonger How can I set it dynamically also so not via the CSS

Comment: You haven't shown us enough code. Without seeing enough CSS and HTML to recreate your issue, I can't offer anything more specific.

Comment: @Blazemonger That's literally it, there's no CSS, I just need to know how to define the image for the back of the flip, can you post an example CSS for that?

Comment: No, we are not here to write your code for you. Search for some [other](http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/flip/) [examples](https://davidwalsh.name/css-flip) and adapt them to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a two sided jQuery flip.

In this example they placed text, you could easily place a img instead.

Since you haven't given much in the way of html, css and only a bit of js directing you here to figure the rest out yourself it all I can do.

https://www.ostraining.com/blog/coding/jquery-flip/

Here is an example of a css flip

http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/flip/

Hope this helps.

Best,

Tim